# How to authorize different roles on a .Net 5 OAuth API

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer4 application, a client application and a .Net 5 API. I want the client application to be able to talk to my API on the users behalf with an access token. Some users should be able to do admin requests while others should only be able to do normal user tasks.

I believe I need to add two scopes for these, api.admin and api.normal.

First question is where would I add these scopes in identityserver? Does the client request both scopes and just gets back whatever IS decides is right for that user?

Secondly, how do I validate what scopes are in the access token on my API. Method 1 should only be used if the access token contains the api.admin scope for eg.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, scopes are something you typically hard-code in your client and it does not "vary" between users. It main purpose is to indicate what the "client" application want to have access to, not the user.

So you only need only one scope like "api".

Then you have different roles or claims in the access-token that describe what the authenticated user have access to.

You then use the authorization middleware in the API to determine what the user actually have access to.

Like what the picture below shows:
[image]

Comment: Is it better to use claims for this or scopes? In the docs here https://docs.identityserver.io/en/3.1.0/topics/apis.html they say to use scopes, so I'm a little confused as I also thought your way was simpler and easier to implement. What is the correct way?

Comment: Scopes is something that is hard-coded into the client application and does not change depending on the user. The scope represent what the client want access to and what the user should consent to. This is more on a application level, not a user level. The final user-access is controlled by the authorization handler and that bases its decision on what is in the ClaimsPrincipal (The User) object. The user also gives consent to let the application use the scopes it requested.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason that different scopes could not be requested by the client based on the user interacting with the client or even environmental based criteria.

As some quick example, a USER that has Authenticated to a Client Application that determines the user is a "Preferred Customer" vs a visitor might be granted scope to allow reading "Preferred Content".

The client then requests a "preferredcontent" scope for the "Preferred Customer" and not for the visitor.

And of course the Authorization Server may reject the scopes requested for any reason.

Comment: The issue I have with this is that I provide what scopes I want from my client before the user is logged in, so I don't know who they are. To do this kind of thing I would have to double back to IS after initial login with new scopes. Thanks for the reply!